# How to create User DSN for *.accdb from commandline in Windows?

Tags: windows, ms-access, command-line, odbc, dsn

I work in an environment where DSN-Less connection is not possible due to some restrictions. I need to create User DSN for `"Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)"`. the .accdb file is located in local disk.

I have tried `C:\>odbcconf configdsn "Microsoft Access Driver (*.
mdb,*.accdb)" "DSN=crt1|SERVER=c:\a.accdb"`. But this doesn't seem to work.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in typing:
`Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`
is correct and works for me (there is a space between *.mdb and *.accdb)

Answer (score 2):

```
odbcconf configdsn "SQL Server" "DSN=fred|Database=dave"
```

works for me. I don't have a 64 bit MS Access driver on this 64 bit machine to try. You don't show the error. Why not add /Lv x.log and see what is in the log file.

However, is this a 64 bit machine? If it is I doubt you've got a 64 bit MS Access driver installed and odbcconf will be attempting to add a 64 bit DSN. If it works with c:\windows\syswow64\odbcconf then that will likely be your answer.

```
c\windows\syswow64\odbcconf configdsn "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)" "DSN=fred;Database=dave"
```

works for me to create a 32 bit DSN.

Comment: Mine is 32 bit OS and 32 bit MS Access. and I need to create DSN for ".accdb" and not ".mdb"

Comment: The example I gave can just as easily be for accdb - just change the driver name.  You've probably just misspelt the driver name. Have you got a space  between "*.mdb," and "*.accdb" because it does not look like it and it has to be exact (it is looked up in a registry key).

Comment: FYI, it's just as easy to create System DSNs, just use `configsysdsn` instead of `configdsn` (in a command prompt with admin priviliges).

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to use the following command.  note the DBQ instead of Database or Server as mentioned in this thread

```
"c:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcconf.exe" CONFIGSYSDSN "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" "DSN=tp_test5;DBQ=c:\trackerpro\database\companydata.mdb"
```